# Scrapy - Getting "None"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am tryimg the table in https://www.iso.org/members.html.

Below is my script:

```
import scrapy


class MemSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mem'
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.iso.org/members.html', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for tr in response.selector.xpath('//tbody/tr'):
            country = tr.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract_first()
            nsb_link = response.urljoin(tr.xpath('./td[2]/a/@href').extract_first())
            nsb_initials = tr.xpath('./td[2]/a/text()').extract_first()
            membership = tr.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract_first()
            tc_particiption = tr.xpath('./tr/td[4]/text()').extract_first()
            pdc_participation = tr.xpath('./tr/td[5]/text()').extract_first()

            print(country,nsb_initials,membership,tc_particiption,pdc_participation,nsb_link)
```

The print function however gives "None" as output for tc_particiption and pdc_participation vairables. I have feeling it could be because of the XPath expression, but I do not know how to go about this.

Kindly see if you can help. I have trying suggestions like setting OBEY Robots to false but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo (no need to use `tr` in your XPath):

```
tc_particiption = tr.xpath('./td[4]/text()').extract_first()
pdc_participation = tr.xpath('./td[5]/text()').extract_first()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I had not seen that. Much much appreciated!